# sharpsvn search repository commits

Tags: sharpsvn

Using sharpsvn I want to search all of the comments on the commited files in our svn server for specific strings.

but i cannot get this to work. I have tried the following but it does not like my target path.

> Error: Revision type requires a working copy path, not a URL

```
SvnRevisionRange range = new SvnRevisionRange(SvnRevision.Working, SvnRevision.Zero);
string targetPath = "http://********:81/svn/";
Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> items;
SvnLogArgs args = new SvnLogArgs { Range = range };
client.GetLog(new Uri(targetPath), args, out items);
```

any ideas would be great

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used:

```
new SvnRevisionRange(SvnRevision.Working, SvnRevision.Zero)
```

It can't determine the revision number of your working copy when you just pass a URL.

Try `SvnRevision.Head` to get the latest version in the repository instead